# Returning a generic struct from new

Tags: generics, rust

I want to return a generic struct. The idea is that I want to have the actual implementation output to STDIN per the standard, but for testing purposes I'd like to substitute it with a vector or something else so I can easily test the output. The solution I have so far is:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Sender<R, W> {
    pub reader: R,
    pub writer: W,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Sender<R, W> {
    pub reader: R,
    pub writer: W,
}

impl<R, W> Sender<R, W> {
    pub fn new<R, W>(reader: R, writer: W) -> Sender<R, W> {
        Sender {
            reader: R,
            writer: W,
        }
    }
}
```

The errors I'm getting:

```
error[E0423]: expected value, found type parameter `R`
  --> src/main.rs:10:21
   |
10 |             reader: R,
   |                     ^ not a value

error[E0423]: expected value, found type parameter `W`
  --> src/main.rs:11:21
   |
11 |             writer: W,
   |                     ^ not a value

error[E0601]: main function not found

error[E0194]: type parameter `R` shadows another type parameter of the same name
 --> src/main.rs:8:16
  |
7 | impl<R, W> Sender<R, W> {
  |      - first `R` declared here
8 |     pub fn new<R, W>(reader: R, writer: W) -> Sender<R, W> {
  |                ^ shadows another type parameter

error[E0194]: type parameter `W` shadows another type parameter of the same name
 --> src/main.rs:8:19
  |
7 | impl<R, W> Sender<R, W> {
  |         - first `W` declared here
8 |     pub fn new<R, W>(reader: R, writer: W) -> Sender<R, W> {
  |                   ^ shadows another type parameter
```

This makes sense to me, it doesn't know the concrete type of `R`. I figured giving the generic parameters in the function would have solved that though, but that gives this additional error:

```
34 | impl<R, W> Sender<R, W> {
   |          - first `R` declared here
35 |   pub fn new<R, W>(reader: R, writer: W) -> Sender<R, W> {
   |              ^ shadows another type parameter
```

That doesn't work because `new<R, W>` declares a *different* (but same named!) `R` and `W`.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't require me to make two different `new` functions, one for memory read/write and the other for STDIN read/write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the syntax used to initialise structs - as it stands, your function is trying to set the `reader` and `writer` fields of the struct to `R` and `W`, not the parameters that you're passing in!

It should look like this:

```
impl<R, W> Sender<R, W> {
    pub fn new(reader: R, writer: W) -> Sender<R, W> {
        Sender {
            reader: reader, // field name on the left, value on the right
            writer: writer,
        }
    }
}
```

Because the struct field and your parameters have the same names, [you can also use the field init shorthand syntax](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1682-field-init-shorthand.md):

```
impl<R, W> Sender<R, W> {
    pub fn new(reader: R, writer: W) -> Sender<R, W> {
        Sender { reader, writer }
    }
}
```

I'd recommend reading [Chapter 5 of 'The Rust Programming Language'](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch05-01-defining-structs.html) if you haven't already - it covers all of this stuff.